# Вывод списка категорий woocommerce на странице

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт на WordPress. Мне нужно вывести иерархический список категорий и подкатегорий woocommerce внутри страницы (page). Есть код, в нем выводятся стандартные рубрики записей WordPress именно в том иерархическом виде как мне нужно, но я не пойму, как его изменить под `product_cat`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<?php

hierarchical_category_tree( 0 ); // the function call; 0 for all categories; or cat ID  

function hierarchical_category_tree( $cat ) {

  $next = get_categories('hide_empty=false&exclude=184&orderby=name&order=ASC&parent=' . $cat);

  if( $next ) :    
    foreach( $next as $cat ) :
    echo '<ul><li>
    <a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Просмотреть товары в %s" ), $cat->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $cat->name . ' ('. $cat->count . ')</a>';

    hierarchical_category_tree( $cat->term_id );
    endforeach;    
  endif;

  echo '</li></ul>'; echo "\n";
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно указать какую именно таксонимию вы хотите отобразить, по умолчанию значение 'category'

```
hierarchical_category_tree( 0 ); 

function hierarchical_category_tree( $cat ) {
    $args = [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'parent' => $cat,
    ];

    $next = get_categories( $args );

    if( $next ) :    
         echo '<ul>';
         foreach( $next as $cat ) :
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Просмотреть товары в %s" ), $cat->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $cat->name . ' ('. $cat->count . ')</a>';

              hierarchical_category_tree( $cat->term_id );
              echo '</li>';
          endforeach;    
          echo '</ul>';
     endif;
}
```